# Reverse ssh SOCKS proxy for 2 servers?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, proxy, reverse-proxy, ssh-tunnel

I can ssh into two servers, A and B. B is very powerful but has limited internet access, while A has full internet access. I can ssh from A to B but not B to A. Given this limitation, how can I set up an ssh SOCKS proxy to tunnel B's internet traffic through A?

I've tried the answer [from this post](https://serverfault.com/a/361806), running both commands on A, where my local server is A and remote is B. I then configured wget on B to use the proxy 127.0.0.1:6666 [according to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211705/how-to-set-proxy-for-wget), editing /etc/wgetrc. However when I attempt to use wget on B, I get:

```
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:6666... connected.
Failed reading proxy response: Success
Retrying.
```

Any ideas? Did I mess up somewhere? Thanks